# SSHDroid cannot write sd card

Tags: ssh, file-permissions

The title says it all.

Running android 7.1 not rooted device, I am running sshDroid on android device, ssh into it from my laptop.

When I ssh into the device and check the permissions for the SD Card it's owned by root.

Without ROOT access, can I ssh and copy files to the SD Card from my machine?

Comment: Have you granted the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to SSHDroid? Some apps have trouble requesting it correctly with runtime permissions. Solution often is to check in *Settings › Apps* and granting the permission manually. As for ownership of the SD card: the group (which also has write access) is the clue here. Once an app has been granted the write permission, it gets added to that group.

Comment: The permissions screen for the app asks for SD Card access and it's granted, still cannot make any edits while connected via ssh or scp.

Comment: That's strange. I remember a similar issue with another app – but I don't remember how it was solved in the end … So let's hope someone comes up with a lightbulb.

Comment: I have the same problem now with SimpleSSHd

Comment: And the same with SSH Server by Banana Studio. What a wonderful world.